# What does SnapsToDevicePixels in WPF mean in layman terms?

Tags: c#, snapstodevicepixels

Anybody? Say I have a Window Class and I give SnapsToDevicePixels = true? what happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will enable [pixel snapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx) for every element in your window as this property is inherited by child UI elements. It won't have an effect on the appearance of the window itself, though (i. e. window frame or similar), since windows reside on integral coordinates on the screen already, anyway.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2024, and we encountered a problem in Visual Studio 2022 where a WPF dialog would show a thick black border on only part of the right edge of the dialog window. SnapsToDevicePixels="True" got rid of the line! ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

If so,your will enable pixel snap rendering throughout the UI.For devices operation at greater than 96 dot per inch (dpi),pixel snap rendering can minimize anti-aliasing visual artifacts in the vicinity of single-unit solid lines.And all child elements of that subtree will then report [SnapToDevicePixes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels.aspx) as true and will have the SnapToDevicePixes visual effect.